# Remove jQuery Tab from dnnTabs Programatically

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs, dotnetnuke-6

I have successfully implemented the jQuery dnnTabs in a custom module.  I am trying to figure out how to programmatically remove a tab.

Here is the javascript for setting up the tabs:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function ($) {
              $('#tabs-demo').dnnTabs();
        });
    </script>
```

Here is the function I created to remove the tag:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function ($) {
            $('#tabs-demo').dnnTabs();
         });
     </script>
```

Here is the function I created to remove the tag:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
         function removeTab(tabID) {
            $('#tabs-demo').dnnTabs('remove', tabID);   
         };
     </script>
```

Here is how I calling the function from the code behind:

```
     ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Me.[GetType](), "tmp", "<script type='text/javascript'>removeTab(1);</script>", False)
```

Tab is not being removed.  I have tried several different iterations, with no luck.

Comment: Is `tabID` the actual ID of the tab or is it some index that dnnTabs uses?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the ModuleSettings control.

The tabs is an unorderd list, and the last last list item has a runat="server" attribute and an id. this tab is used for module-specific settings. It is hidden when there are none (or the programmer has put them in an extra control with an action link from the modules action menu).

```
<ul class="dnnAdminTabNav dnnClear">
    <li><a href="#msModuleSettings"><%=LocalizeString("ModuleSettings")%></a></li>
    <li><a href="#msPermissions"><%=LocalizeString("Permissions")%></a></li>
    <li><a href="#msPageSettings"><%=LocalizeString("PageSettings")%></a></li>
    <li id="specificSettingsTab" runat="server">
        <asp:HyperLink href="#msSpecificSettings" ID="hlSpecificSettings" runat="server" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

The visibility of the last tab is handled in the control's OnLoad event, the "else" part makes it invisible:

```
                //Set visibility of Specific Settings
                if (SettingsControl == null == false)
                {
                    //Get the module settings from the PortalSettings and pass the
                    //two settings hashtables to the sub control to process
                    SettingsControl.LoadSettings();
                    specificSettingsTab.Visible = true;
                    fsSpecific.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    specificSettingsTab.Visible = false;
                    fsSpecific.Visible = false;
                }
```

Hope it helps!
Michael

Answer (score 0):

You could try to skip the `dnnTabs('remove')` and just remove it from the DOM with jQuery:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     function removeTab(tabID) {
        $('#tabs-demo '+tabID).remove();   
     };
 </script>
```

Comment: John,

Thanks for your quick response. Unfortunately that did not work.  I wanted to make sure that you knew that the TabID is an index, and not an textual ID.

Comment: John, it looks like that would have worked as well.  I just needed to wrap my function with a jquery funcion call.  I will post it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thankd to John and Brian Dukes for getting me on the right path.

Here is the ultimate fix:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
         function removeTab(tabID) {
             jQuery(function ($) {
                 $('#tabs-demo').tabs('remove', tabID);
             });
         };
    </script>
```